# checked radio button after check one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two radio buttons as bellow:

```
<label for="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender1" id="male" value="male1"><br>
</label>
```

How can I checked both of them by click on just one?
For example click on first radio and checked first and second one

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you question. Do you want to have a third button when clicked selects both radio buttons? Also my impression of radio buttons is that it forces you to select one - you may want to rethink the UI/UX implications of allowing both to be clicked. Perhaps take a look at using checkboxes instead.

Comment: Why do you have one label around two inputs with the same ID (which is invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute [***id***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, use [***class***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. On clicking any button you can set the *checked* attribute to *true*:

```js
$('.male').click(function(){
  $('.male').attr('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" class="male" value="male"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender1" class="male" value="male1"><br>
</label>
```

Comment: tnq that's it  @Mamun

Answer (score 1):

Each id can only be used once per page. So I changed it to male1 and male2.

```js
let male1 = document.querySelector("#male1");
let male2 = document.querySelector("#male2");

male1.addEventListener("input", () => {
    male2.checked = "true";
});

male2.addEventListener("input", () => {
    male1.checked = "true";
});
```

```html
<label for="male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male1" value="male"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender1" id="male2" value="male1"><br>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a click listener on parent element of both radio inputs and whenever any of the radio input is clicked, you check all of them via javascript

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  radioInputs.forEach(i => i.checked = true);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <label for="male">Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender1" id="male1" value="male1"><br>
    </label>
 </div>
```

**Side Note:** id of each element should be unique. You should not use id on both radio inputs